# react native, show a bar above of TabNavigator, who hide on scroll ( like facebook app do)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm devolopping an app with react native.

I use `tabNavigator` and `StackNavigator` from `react-navigation` to navigate between tabs.

Now i want to create , exactly like the facebook's app, a tab displayed above my `tabNavigator`. This tabs hide on scroll down.

The `FlatList` component have `ListHeaderComponent` option for rendering his header who also hide when scroll down.

Any idea ? 
I didn't found anything on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/ or react-native docs

[image]

Comment: @Alainlb: have you find solution for this? I am also struggling with this. I am able to scroll the top bar when I am using single component. Now I am using TabbarNavigator. I am not getting how to achieve this. Do you have any sample for it.

Comment: @Sujit. no i don't found anything this this post was created. :< let me know please if you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a TabNavigator nested inside a StackNavigator, like below

```
StackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: {
      screen: TabNavigator(
        {
          TabA: {
            screen: TabA,
            navigationOptions: {
              tabBarIcon: <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"account"} />
            }
          },
          TabB: {
            screen: TabB,
            navigationOptions: {
              tabBarIcon: <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"message"} />
            }
          },
          TabC: {
            screen: TabC,
            navigationOptions: {
              tabBarIcon: <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"earth"} />
            }
          }
        },
        {
          tabBarOptions: {
            showLabel: false,
            showIcon: true,
            style: {
              backgroundColor: "white"
            }
          }
        }
      ),
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Notifications"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerRight: <MaterialCommunityIcons name={"magnify"} size={30} style={{ color: "white" }} />,
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "rgb(76, 62, 84)"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: { color: "white" }
    })
  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but are you sure ?  i already use stackNavigator, a StackNavigator open a fullscreen modal over all the phone screen. I want to display just a bar like the one in red rectangle

Comment: Check edit. Works fine for me. Just mocked it up and added a screenshot also

Comment: yes thanks it display . did you know how to hide it when scroll down ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have experience with that, but I would assume it is some combination of checking offset of scrollview inside ScrollView's onScroll event, and using navigation.setParams to set headerMode to "none" if scroll is beyond a certain point